# Does pdfbox version 2.0.17 have memory leak issue?

Tags: pdfbox

We are using the pdfbox 2.0.17 to process pdf files, and render each page to image files. We notice that for some large pdf files (about 3000 pages), the JVM crashed with OutOfMemory error after processing 2900 pages, but it's random, the page at which the JVM crashes varies in each run, and in some runs, the code can even complete processing. That leads us to think that there might be memory leak happening, and depends on the time of GC, the JVM could crash or survive.

I'm wondering, was there any known memory leak issues in the version pdfbox 2.0.17? If so, what are the conditions would trigger the leak? Are there any improvement in the area of memory usage in the version 2.0.19?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: PDFBox is always improved with each version, although I don't remember any specifics on memory leaks for a long time. And so is java, so make sure that both are up to date.

Comment: If there was a real memory leak, garbage collection would not help.

Comment: Sounds more like that you VM needs some more heap space. If you suspect a memory leak then analyze it using e.g. jvisualVM or the like.